# Why are water bubbles created at the top of the bottle if the water level is higher?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, flow, bubbles

Water bubbles created at the top of the bottle if the water level is higher:

[image]

but water bubbles is not created at the top of the bottle if the water level is lower:

[image]

This [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/429497/why-do-the-bubbles-in-the-water-cooler-get-larger-as-the-level-gets-lower) is very different from this one and [this](https://images.meesho.com/images/products/231448136/tqrtj_512.webp) is how what my drawing look in reality.

Why are water bubbles created at the top of the bottle if the water level is higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for water to leave the upper tank, air must enter it through the same opening as the water leaves. This creates the bubbling effect as the upper tank is emptied - it is like filling a bottle with water, then turning it upside down.

However, if the seal between the upper tank and the lower tank is not air tight then air can enter the lower tank around this seal. So as water leaves the lower tank through the lower drain, then air enters it around the drain from the upper tank. The flow of water from the drain does not have to be interrupted to allow air to enter through the drain, and so no bubbles appear in the lower tank.